# File Extensions

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

I’ve been tasked with auditing a certain computer. I was advised that the owner of the computer might have deleted some evidence before handing it over. Upon inspecting the file system, I found to my relief that no files had been recently deleted, and all their contents and time stamps were intact. But I noticed something very odd: all of the file extensions had been removed. Here is the file listing of the disk:

```
audio/homophonescompressed.___              02:17:05
audio/homophonesrawrecording.___            03:13:00
emus/wine/system32/recyclebin.___           15:04:10
emus/wine/system32/spinninghourglass.___    19:16:07
puzzling/prooffermatslast.___               09:21:20
puzzling/theultimatechessstrategy.___       12:00:06
scripts/bash/wordmatcher.__                 22:01:00
scripts/python/anagramer.__                 11:14:00
scripts/typescript/rot13.__                 18:08:00
```

Who am I and what has the owner of this computer been up to?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Who am I and what has the owner of this computer been up to?

> You are working for a fiscal authority and are trying to find evidence of tax evasion.

The file extensions ...

> ... can be derived from the nature of the files. They are:
>
>      **.oga**: an OGG Audio file
>      **.wav**: an uncompressed sound file
>      **.ico**: an icon
>      **.ani**: an animated cursor
>      **.tex**: a TeX source file for typesetting formulas
>      **.pgn**: the portable game notation for chess games
>      **.sh**: a shell script
>      **.py**: a Python script
>      **.ts**: a typescript source file

The timestamps ...

> ... have the curious property that each number from 1 to 22 appears only once, either as hour, minute or second. They probably represent a kind of order. There's also a correspondence between the three letters of the file extension to the three numbers (hh:mm:ss) in the timestamp. (For the files with two-letter extensions, the seconds are zero.)
>
>  The letters from the extensions and the hh:mm:ss numbers can be seen as sequences. The first letters are O, G, A, W, A, V, …; the first numbers are 02, 17, 05, 03, 13, 00, …
>
>  Now create 22 empty slots. Put the first letter O into slot 02; put the G in slot 17 and so on. (If the number is 00, do nothing.) A message is spelled out:
>
>  **HOW CAN I STOP PAYING TAXES**

The answer to which is

> **FILE EXTENSIONS**

Comment: @M Oehm, Very nice, everything in your answer is exactly right. However it is missing a final step that @JLee has almost identified: what is the answer to the question you have discovered? hint: rot13(gjb jbeqf)

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me extend the answer ...

Comment: @MOehm, nice job. You've solved it. Sorry I made the final answer so convoluted. Mind if I make a slight edit?

Comment: Not at all. I had an inkling that I was missing something, but I just couldn't see it.

Comment: Note that in the US at least, you must still pay your taxes on time. Filing an extension only grants you additional time to file the paperwork.

Comment: @pacoverflow To learn the very limited nature of the U.S. federal income tax, and start paying only what you owe (which is zero for most of us), see [here](http://www.realtaxtruth.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/TheNatureOfTheTax.pdf), [here](http://www.realtaxtruth.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/PlainFactsAboutTheTax.pdf), and [here](https://www.realtaxtruth.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/BriefAndBright.pdf) for more. You're welcome.